# TCP Socket between ESP32 and python script not working after ESP32 reset

Tags: python, arduino, esp32

I have an ESP32 opening a simple TCP server and a python script accessing as client.
Things are going quite smooth, but when the ESP32 reset (e.g. after a power loss) or when no connection is made directly after powering the ESP, the client cannot connect any more.

ESP Server code, using Arduino Core(shortend):

```
#include <WiFi.h>
WiFiServer server(23);
void setup() {
  server.begin();
}
void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  if (client) {

    if (client.connected()) {
      Serial.println("Client connected");
      lastConnection = timeNow;

    if (client.available()) {
      Serial.println("Data to be read");
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\n'); 
      Serial.println(line);
    } 

    if (timeSendWs < timeNow) { 
      Serial.println("Sending data");
      String msg = notifyClients(); //notifyClients() build the message that is to be send  
      char *cmsg = &msg[0];
      client.write(cmsg);
      timeSendWs = timeNow + TIME_SEND_WS;
    }
  }  
  Serial.println("Disconnecting");
  client.stop();
}

if (lastConnection < timeNow - 2 * TIME_SEND_WS) {
   Serial.println("Connection interrupted for too long");
   client.stop();
   Stopping(); //Some action that needs to taken, when not connection could be established for some time 
   lastConnection = timeNow;
}
}
```

Python script

```
 while True:
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(2)
        s.connect(('192.168.2.251', 23))
        s.sendall('hi\n'.encode()) # Include \n to ensure faster processing

        data = []
        while True:
            chunk = s.recv(1024)
            if not chunk: break  # When the other side closes the socket, chunk = ''
            data.append(chunk.decode())
        all_data = ''.join(data)
        if len(all_data) > 0:
            print(all_data)
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)
    s.close()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The errors I get on python side are either "timeout" or "[Errno 64] Host is down" and just before reconnecting "[Errno 61] Connection refused"

Comment: `Accept` not an thread but send and recive is new thread. `Serial.println("Disconnecting");
  client.stop();` why stop requesting ? Both side waiting for what? `While sender `work with `while receiver`. You got two server, not an client-server pair.

Comment: Thanks @dsgdfg for your comment, however, I have to admit that I do not understand it. 
For the Arduino bit, I used the examples provided in the WiFi documentation plus some tutorials, as I have no in-depth understanding . 
For Python, as to my (also limited) understanding, a sever would include some "bind" and "listen" commands.
It would be of great help, if you could more clearly suggest what I should change.

Comment: Make an server on python (PC side) and arduino any-server work very slowly, then try some packet send or recieve. I imagine you missing a lot TCP connection rules. So connect is different and send-receive another part of communication(TCP).  You can't make an connection on *byte-level*, need change some library on arduino side(also work on limited hardware(not all)).  Use *http packets* as raw communications than ignore some bytes/string for claim your *data*. I hope is helpfull ! Have nice day !